# How can ı add vertical scroll bar in widget?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, scrollbar

Im a junior developer in android.I created the widgets. I want to add vertical scroll bar in my widget.How can i do this? Thanks.

My Widget Codes:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    int id = 0;
    if (MyNotesWidgetActivity.widgetProcess == "create") {
        id = CustomAdapter.cid;
    } else{
        id = CustomAdapter.uid;
    }
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(context);
    dataSource.open();
    String content = dataSource.getNote(id);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notes_widget);

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, content);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorMyBlue"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorMyBlue"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:text="@string/add_widget"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: I'm taking widget content from user-added notes. Too long content doesn't fit in the widget.
Not all content is visible.
So I want to add a scroll bar to the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with 
single-element listview structure.

I hope helpful for your problem.

[WidgetScrollBar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQO0GpSXLjYJsdD50SgTaWjQYURDkTkK/view)

Answer (score 0):

**Option - 1 :** Use `ScrollView` to make the view Scrollable

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorMyBlue"
        android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorMyBlue"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
            android:text="@string/add_widget"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />  
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Option - 2:** Just set the `scrollbars` property in your `TextView` in `layout.xml`

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

And then set `setMovementMethod` to `ScrollingMovementMethod` in your code

```
[appwidget_text].setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Then try with option 2

Comment: [appwidget_text].setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());           how can ı reach to [appwidget_text] (TextView object) from RemoteView object  ?  Or what is the way to reach this object  ?

Comment: ScrollView is not supported in widget, so the 1st solution will simply not work at all.